# Not able to import en_core_web_sm or Spacy

Tags: machine-learning, pip, anaconda, conda, spacy

I am trying to import `en_core_web_sm` as independent package and also tried through `spacy`. But I am getting an error in ujson module in both case.

Error :

> **`ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'srsly.ujson.ujson'`**

I installed `en_core_web_sm` through following command

`python -m spacy download en_core_web_sm`

Going by `Spacy` documentation it shall work. But it is not. I want to import `en_core_web_sm`.

Answer (score 0):

`srsly` [listed](https://github.com/explosion/spaCy/blob/4f1dae1c6bc8f72bef2594dee6ee0a6c0fdb602c/setup.py#L236) as a dependency so it should be installed. If it's not installed just install it yourself:

```
python -m pip install srsly
```