# AWS Lambda -- Unable to import srsly.ujson.ujson for SpaCy

Tags: python, amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, spacy, ujson

I am trying to add SpaCy as a dependency to my Python Lambda. I am doing this by installing SpaCy as a standalone dependency inside a directory named `dependencies` using `pip3 install spacy --no-deps -t .` This is because I can't load the entire Spacy dependency inside the `\tmp` directory of my Lambda.

I am able to successfully upload the folder to s3 and download it during the Lambda invocation. When I try to `import spacy`, I get this error: `[ERROR] Runtime.ImportModuleError: Unable to import module : No module named 'srsly.ujson.ujson'`.

I manually installed `srsly` inside `dependencies\` and I have all the files that are listed as per [this link](https://github.com/explosion/srsly/tree/master/srsly/ujson). This was referenced by [this link](https://github.com/explosion/srsly/issues/3). One of the responses says, "it seems like Python can't load it, because it's not compiled?". How would I compile a dependency which has a `.c` file in it?

One other question which I found on SO is [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56895324/not-able-to-import-en-core-web-sm-or-spacy), but I have already manually installed `srsly`. How to I import the module? Thanks.

---

I manually check in my code for the presence of `ujson` before importing spacy like this:

```py
if os.path.exists('/tmp/dependencies/srsly/ujson/ujson.c'):
    print('ujson exists')
```

and the print statement gets printed.

Comment: What version of spacy are you using? And where do you run pip install? I'm facing a similar issue and I think that the problem is that I run pip install on my machine, but lambda runtime uses aws linux and C dependencies that were compliled on my machine do not work there.

Comment: @AlexeySmirnov I am running pip install inside a folder `/tmp/python` as `pip3 install spacy --no-deps -t .` . Yes, I think the issue might also be with python3.6 vs python3.7.

Comment: If you run pip install on your local machine, then zips the dependencies, and then uploads for lambda to use it means that some binaries were compiled using you OS compiler which is different from  lambda runtime os - amazonlinux

Answer (score 1):

For me pip uninstalling and installing srsly again worked fine.. sometimes its just the compatibility issue with your python version so make sure correct python/srsly versions are present

Answer (score 0):

Well it is a bit strange, but my solution for this problem was to create an aditional "ujson" folder in the srsly folder and then move all the ujson generated code to the folder "ujson" previously created